# Display iframe or embeded posts on homepage

Tags: posts, embed

In my Blog there are many blog posts with a combination of iframe video posts and images posts.

I need to filter the posts in two categories

1) Posts with Video (iframe or embeded)

2) Posts with images

Comment: i am sorry, my question is related to wordpress blog not wordpress.com. i am trying to add wordpress tag but i am not able to add my own tag thats why i added like(wordpress.com).
can you please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: Please make sure you read the tag descriptions before using them. Wrong tagging can lead to your question being wrongly closed. I have retagged your question :-). Just to add, this site is for Wordpress, so there will be no wordpress tag

Comment: thank you pieter,
is there any possibilities to solve my question ?